# Using qgis:lineintersection in QGIS console?

Tags: qgis-plugins

console usage for qgis:lineintersection processing tool has been given as below

```
processing.runalg('qgis:lineintersections', input_a, input_b, field_a, field_b, output)
```

and i loaded a polyline layer onto qgis and executed following commands in console

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

columns = provider.fields()

id=columns[0]

processing.runalg('qgis:lineintersections', layer, layer, id, id,'output' )
```

lineintersection tool is working properly when i use it directly in qgis, but i want to execute it in console for which i m getting error as below .......

---

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py",
>   line 71, in runalg
>       alg = Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, None, *args)   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py",
>   line 317, in runAlgorithm
>       if not param.setValue(args[i]):   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\parameters.py",
>   line 676, in setValue
>       elif len(value) > 0: TypeError: object of type 'QgsField' has no len()

---

i think problem is with passing values in function

Can anyone give the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out this code:

```
import processing

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/my_output.shp'

processing.runalg('qgis:lineintersections', layer, layer, None, None, path )
```

for this situation:

[image]

and it worked. You don't need the id's (see the error 'QgsField' has no len() where I think the problem is). On the other hand, I used one absolute path and the name of output file with its respective extension (*.shp).